# Is it ever good to use Razor views as AngularJS views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

When, if ever, is it appropriate to render an angular partial view using Razor?

Comment: Well I don't know anything about Razor but my general feeling is that if you don't need it why introduce a whole extra layer of templating? Is there something Razor provides you with that Angular's templates can't handle or don't do well?  The nice thing about sticking with "The Angular Way" is that things are pretty darn well decoupled and can DI just about everything which means testing is easier.  Introducing other libraries/ways of doing things will undoubtedly complicate the decoupling.

Comment: Razor views work on server, angular on client so there is clear demarcation. Can you give a scenario and explain your question better?

Comment: I guess the scenario would be applying Security logic to the view itself.  If some part needs to be hidden or shown, you could avoid rendering it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generally tried to stay away from mixing server side rendering with client-side rendering when using Angular but I have found it convenient to sometimes:

- Set variables/data that is known server-side

An example might be a client API key that you might want to use client-side without making an additional call to a backend for that information.

Here is an example of a template:

```
<div config="{ soundcloudApiKey: '@soundcloudApiKey' }">
</div>
```

Where `@soundcloudApiKey` is presumably available in a model server-side and `config` is a directive that brings data from the markup into your Angular code in case you want to use it elsewhere:

```
myModule.directive('config', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        // you can save config to a service and use it elsewhere
        var config = scope.$eval(attrs.config);
        console.log(config.soundcloudApiKey);
      }
    };
  });
```

Note: there is likely a cleaner way to get to this type of configuration data like via a login process or an explicit call for config settings but I've used this type of thing in the past and it works just fine!